# Counting paths in a matrix - Backtracking

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix, backtracking

Given an M*N matrix, I want to calculate the total number of possible paths from the upper-left cell (0,0) to the lower-right cell (m-1, n-1). Possible movements include <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, and <kbd>left</kbd>. A path is considered valid only if it visits each cell c(i, j) exactly once. If going beyond the matrix boundaries or encountering a previously visited cell, the recursion is cut.

```
if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= m || y >= n || grid[x][y] == 1) {
        return;
    }
```

To limit the number of recursions, I thought of some obvious improvements:

- if reaching the final cell before visiting all cells, the path won't be valid;
- if reaching a border cell, i.e., a cell of the form (i, n-1) or (m-1, j), and the cells immediately above and below (or to the right and left) haven't been visited, then it will be impossible to form valid paths;
- Similarly, if encountering a previously visited cell and having the option to move in two different directions, that path will not be valid (indeed, we are dividing the matrix into two zones of unvisited cells)

I am trying to implement

```
void CountPath(int x, int y, int n, int m)
```

in C++ using backtracking, could you suggest me some ways to proceed?

*My idea is to maintain a boolean matrix to represent the grid and, at each step, after checking various conditions, call CountPath(x, y, n, m) with modified parameters x, y based on the corresponding movement (setting the cell on which CountPath is called to 1).*

EDIT: After doing some tests, I have come up with this code that seems to be working. I still have some issues determining the conditions under which the path encounters a point where it divides the matrix into two zones with unvisited cells.
Note that I used a matrix of size N*M for this implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
/*
    N*M matrix

0<=x<M
0<=y<N


*/


void CountPaths(int x, int y, int M, int N, ll &paths, vector<vector<bool>> &grid, int k)
{ 
    if (x == M-1 && y == N-1 && k == N*M){
        paths++;
        return;
    } // correct path

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= M || y >= N || grid[y][x] == true) {
        return;
    } // beyond boundaries

    if(x == M-1 && y == N-1 && k!=M*N) return; // c(n-1, m-1) - some grid[i][j]=0
    if (y == N-1 && 0<x && x<M-1 && !grid[y][x-1] && !grid[y][x+1]) return; // c(n-1, j)
    if (x == M-1 && 0<y && y<N-1 && !grid[y-1][x] && !grid[y+1][x]) return; // c(i, m-1)
    if (y == 0 && 0<x && x<M-1 && !grid[y][x-1] && !grid[y][x+1]) return; // c(0, j)
    if (x == 0 && 0<y && y<N-1 && !grid[y-1][x] && !grid[y+1][x]) return; // c(i, 0)


    grid[y][x] = 1;
    CountPaths(x + 1, y, N, M, paths, grid, k + 1); // right
    CountPaths(x, y + 1, N, M, paths, grid, k + 1); // down
    CountPaths(x - 1, y, N, M, paths, grid, k + 1); // left
    CountPaths(x, y - 1, N, M, paths, grid, k + 1); // up
    grid[y][x] = 0; // backtracking
}



int main(void){

    int N = 9; // row
    int M = 9; // column
    vector<vector<bool>> grid(N, vector<bool>(M, false));
    ll paths = 0;
    CountPaths(0, 0, M, N, paths, grid, 1);

   //freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    cout << "Number of paths in a " << N << "x" << M << " matrix: " << paths << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I am trying to implement"*: is there a problem while implementing your bullet points? Any outputs that are wrong? What exactly is your question, as obviously the way to proceed is to write the code?

Comment: *"if reaching a border cell, i.e., a cell of the form (i, n-1) or (m-1, j), and the cells immediately above and below (or to the right and left) haven't been visited, then it will be impossible to form valid paths;"* << This is true also for the two other borders, ie cells of the form (i, 0) or (0, j)

Comment: It's also true that it will be impossible to visit all cells if you create a "loop" with both an interior and an exterior, for instance if you move from cell A=(i, j) to cell B=(i+1, j) while having already visited a cell C among [(i+1, j+1), (i+2, j+1), (i+2, j), (i+2, j-1), (i+1, j-1)] and having unvisited cells D and E adjacent to B with D "on the left" and E "on the right" of A->B->C.

Comment: It looks like all you have done is copy your question here but done no thinking yet ->This does not clear the bar for [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/20143744): no sign of a good faith attempt, the question is a *I have no idea where to start* plea. I suggest you get away from your IDE right now and try to find a logic/pattern with a paper and a pen. Once you have found something interesting, you are welcome to come back to the site and share what you have done. Someone will likely be able to connect the dots.

Comment: *"My idea is to maintain a boolean matrix to represent the grid and, at each step, after checking various conditions, call CountPath(x, y, n, m) with modified parameters x, y based on the corresponding movement (setting the cell on which CountPath is called to 1)."* << That is a great idea but note that you need to have some way to backtrack. So insead of setting the previous cell to 1, I suggest setting the previous cell to k, when k is the number of steps so far. This way when you encounter a dead-end you can easily find which cells you come from and backtrack the path step by step.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help, I've understood how it works the section and now I'll post the code: please be lenient as I'm just starting out ;)

Comment: @Stef Based on what you mentioned in the comment, I would think of it this way, but I am struggling to determine the condition to write in the code.. If I consider a generic cell c(i, j) and one of the cells in the next column in the form d0(i+1, j-1), d1(i+1, j), d2(i+1, j+1) is set to true, having the two cells A(i, j+1) and B(i, j-1) available, I would divide the matrix into two zones that are no longer visitable. The same thing happens when analyzing groups of 5 cells located to the left, above, or below c(i, j). (?)

Comment: @BeeP Yes, detecting this kind of loop is much harder than just detecting that you reached a border. I suggest first writing the code while ignoring this condition about loops. And then when you have code that works, you can try to improve it by adding this condition about loops.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you a pseudocode, using guards and list comprehension for brevity and succinctness. It's a simple recursive algorithm.

I'm showing the square `N*N` case, which you can adapt for your more general rectangular case.

```php
Paths(n) = paths(n, [(0,0)])
paths(n, [p, ...ps])
  | p == (n-1, n-1) = 
      length(ps)==(n^2-1) ? 1 : 0
  | outside?(n, p) = 0
  | member?(p, ps) = 0
  | otherwise = sum [ 
      paths(n, [q, p, ...ps])
      FOR q IN fourDirections(p) ]
```

Recursion is a problem-solving tool. Its approach is *thinking in the small*. We just do a simple partition step - here, realizing the 4 possible moves in the simplest terms - then, combine the recursively found results, again in the simplest terms, here, summing up the four *results*. Letting recursion take care of all the bookkeeping.

The key is designing the algorithm to be *independent* of other invocations, passing all the info it needs as the arguments. This way, maintaining *validity* needs no additional attention whatsoever.